# How to validate password in my passwordfield from mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, validation, jtextfield

I'm using mysql database.

My code is working when i used Name and ID to validate from database.
But when  i used password for validation, i cant because it's hashed/encrypted.
I want that if the password from the database matched to the id then success

my button for validation:
TEACHER is my table

```
try {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/GradeSystem";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "";

        com.mysql.jdbc.Connection con = (com.mysql.jdbc.Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        String sql="SELECT * from TEACHER";

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        String user=TID.getText();//variable name of my firsttxtfield
        String pwd= new String (TPASS.getText());//variable name of my 2nd txtfield
        int tmp=0;
        while(rs.next()) {
            String uname=rs.getString("TID");//TID name in my database
            String pssword=rs.getString("TPASS"); //TID name in my database
            if ((user.equals(uname)) && (pwd.equals(pssword)))
            {
                this.dispose();
                new TeacherAccount().setVisible(true);

                tmp++;

            }
        }
        if (tmp==0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Password and Username!");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }//i know my code is unclean im trying to implement first :)
```

Any idea how to solve this or any other walkaround to implement the same? sorry bad english.

Comment: You have to hash the password given too, then compare it.

Comment: i use this to insert to mysql : Password.getText() and retrieved Password.getText() = this works(ofc the password is visible). But i when i use to insert Password.getPassword, i cant use Password.getPassword? How to get the password ?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point is you're not storing the raw password. So there's no way a comparison of two unlike strings will be true. So, you'd need something like this-

`if(encodedPassword.equals(encode(rawPassword))) { /* They passed */ }`

This would compare the raw string with the one encoded in the database. I would suggest you investigate the code that inserts passwords in the db and use the same technique.

Comment: Thanks both of you guys !!. I used  in inserting for now is the Password.getText(getText is strikethrough) in storing to my db THAN Password.getPassword.  Because if i used Password.getPassword in storing i dunno why i cant use Password.getPassword in retrieving. this is my code in selecting from db              String pwd= new String (TPASS.getText());

Comment: @Tiny, I removed the Spring references based on your comment. Seems to be less clear now IMHO.

Comment: @SevyNnez, I'm not understanding you. Unless there's something funny going on, I'm not sure how `getPassword` would insert anything. Can you add the entire code block in question to your post?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this wrong. You shouldn't be comparing the password at all. Let the database do that, using its hashing functions, the same ones that it uses when storing the password. What you're interested in is one thing and one thing only:

- is there a user with this username and this password?

So your SQL should look something like

```
select count(*) from users where tid = ? and tpass = ?
```

where the second ? may be replaced by *f(?)* for some *f*.

The reason is that you don't want to leak, even to your own application, any information to the effect that the userID was wrong, or it was right but the password was wrong. All you care is 'user exists' or 'no such user'. You don't want the attacker to know which it was, and the fail-safe way to accomplish that is where you don't know that yourself. Only the database knows.

Comment: I was just going to suggest this. Great job!

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind this is if you are storing password as raw in database then compare

```
inputRawPassword.equals(dbRawpassword)
```

if the password is stored as hashed then for the raw password as user input  again hash it with the same algorithm that you used to hash while storing in database and then compare the two hashes i.e

```
hashInputPassword = hashFunction(intputRawPassowd);
hashInputPassword.equals(dbHashPassword)
```

hope it helps you